# how to set the asp.net calendar to show only the specific date range

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, date

I am working on an etime application that has a drop-down list for paygroup and based on the pay group selected the employee drop down-list with in that paygroup is populated i then take the dates they have transactions for and do a min and max on those dates and fill the AvailableDateRange MIN-MAX. The question i have is i would like the calendar to only display the min and max date range for the from date and to date any thing greater than the max and anything less than the min should be greyed out. Any Help will be appreciated

[image]

**The default.aspx code**

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="PayGroup"></asp:Label>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="25px" 
        Width="190px" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        DataTextField="Paygroup" DataValueField="Paygroup" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EtimeHistoryConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Paygroup FROM dbo.EtimeEmployees GROUP BY Paygroup">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Employee"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="428px" 
        AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="employee" 
        DataValueField="empid" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EtimeHistoryConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Paygroup, EtimeEmpID AS empid, EmpName + ' - ' + EtimeEmpID AS employee FROM EtimeEmployees WHERE (Paygroup = @paygroup) ORDER BY EmpName">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="paygroup" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EtimeHistoryConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT MIN(TransDate) AS mindate, MAX(TransDate) AS maxdate FROM dbo.EtimePunchDetail WHERE (EmpID = @empid)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="empid" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="AvailableDateRange MIN-MAX"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="mindate" 
        DataValueField="mindate" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="-&gt;"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="maxdate" 
        DataValueField="maxdate" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="From Date" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFCC" 
            BorderColor="#FFCC66" BorderWidth="1px" DayNameFormat="Shortest" 
            Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#663399" Height="200px" 
            ondayrender="Calendar1_DayRender" 
            ShowGridLines="True" Width="945px" SelectionMode="None">
            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" Font-Bold="True" />
            <SelectorStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="White" />
            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#CC9966" />
            <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
            <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" Height="1px" />
            <TitleStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="9pt" 
                ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
        </asp:Calendar>
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="To Date" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFCC" 
            BorderColor="#FFCC66" BorderWidth="1px" DayNameFormat="Shortest" 
            Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#663399" Height="200px" 
            ShowGridLines="True" Width="945px">
            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" Font-Bold="True" />
            <SelectorStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="White" />
            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#CC9966" />
            <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
            <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" Height="1px" />
            <TitleStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="9pt" 
                ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
        </asp:Calendar>
```

**I Tried This**

```
 protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Day.Date == DateTime.Parse(DropDownList3.Text))
            {
                e.Day.IsSelectable = true;
            }
            if (e.Day.Date < DateTime.Parse(DropDownList3.Text))
            {
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by handling the DayRender event:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date > DateTime.Now)    // use any selection criteria
    {
        // you can do all kinds of stuff here
        e.Cell.Enabled = false;
        e.Cell.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Steve Wellens  sir i tried your suggestion i have added the code i tired in the question but that event is not getting fired what am i doing wrong, plz help

Comment: It looks OK, are you sure it's not firing?   Did you place a breakpoint in the function?

Comment: Yup pretty sure, it is suppose to take the dropdownlist3.text's date and set it to the calendar's date but that is not happening, i have auto postback set to true, im thinking that the calendar takes a date parameter but the dropdownlist contains a datetime, so could that be the issue if so how can i convert that value to date string? plz help.

Comment: The DayRender event runs at the server as the calendar is built before it is sent to the client.   I copied and pasted your aspx code and C# function signature code to a page and it worked.   I put a breakpoint on the function and it triggers.   It triggers once for each day rendered.